# event target id being undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am not sure why my onclick handler is receiving undefined reading id here.

react-dom.development.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at clickHandler

```
 const clickHandler = (event) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
      let buttonID=event.target.id;
      console.log("button ID is ",buttonID);
      if(buttonID==="cancelButton"){
        console.log("it is cancel button here");


      }
      else{
        console.log("it is not cancel button here");
      }
      setVisible(false);
      event.preventDefault();
   }

export const something: FunctionComponent<somethingProps> = (props) => {
return( // some code some code
        <Modal
            onDismiss={() => setVisible(false)}
            visible={visible}
            closeAriaLabel="Close modal"
            size="small"
           footer={
             <Box float="right">
               <SpaceBetween direction="horizontal" size="xs">
                 <Button variant="link" onClick={clickHandler} id="cancelButton">Cancel</Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={clickHandler} id="okButton">Confirm</Button>
              </SpaceBetween>
            </Box>
          }
            header={`Would you like to publish timeline?`}
        >
          <span>
              <p> Publishing timeline for this launch will send out approval request to GM. </p>
          </span>
      </Modal>
    )
};
```

Comment: can you log "event". is a target there? is a currentTarget there? not sure what Button is wrapping around the actual button here.

Comment: If you want the element that the event handler was attached to, that's `currentTarget` not `target`. We don't know what `Button` is, of course, but assuming it's a wrapper for `button`, it wouldn't be uncommon for that to have other elements inside it (like spans).